# S3 boto3 refuses to overwrite endpoint URL

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, endpoint

I'm working on an internal S3 service (not AWS one). When I provide hard coded credentials, region and endpoint_url, boto3 seems to ignore them.

I came to that conclusion because it is attempting to go on internet (by using a public aws endpoint URL instead of the internal I have provided) but it does not work because of the following proxy error. But he should not go on internet, since it is an internal S3 service :

botocore.exceptions.ProxyConnectionError: Failed to connect to proxy URL: "http://my_company_proxy"

Here is my code

```
import io
import os
import boto3
import pandas as pd


# Method 1 : Client ######################################### 


s3_client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    region_name='EU-WEST-1',
    aws_access_key_id='xxx',
    aws_secret_access_key='zzz',
    endpoint_url='https://my_company_enpoint_url'
)

# ==> at this point no error, but I don't know the value of endpoint_url

# Read bucket
bucket = "bkt-udt-arch"
file_name = "banking.csv"
print("debug 1") # printed OK
obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket= bucket, Key= file_name) 

# program stops here : 

botocore.exceptions.ProxyConnectionError: Failed to connect to proxy URL: "http://my_company_proxy"

print("debug 2") # not printed - 
initial_df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body']) # 'Body' is a key word
print("debug 3") 


# Method 2 : Resource ######################################### 

# use third party object storage
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', endpoint_url='https://my_company_enpoint_url',
    aws_access_key_id='xxx',
    aws_secret_access_key='zzz',
    region_name='EU-WEST-1'
    )

 print("debug 4") # Printed OK if method 1 is commented

# Print out bucket names
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
 print(bucket.name)
```

Comment: Your code as written works without any problems for me when accessing a local S3 service. It sounds like you may just have a bad proxy configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the review
It was indeed a proxy problem :  when http_prxoxy env variable is disabled, it works fine.